# How to execute left outer join asynchronously? when the join is on the where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to optimize the following query, let's say I have 2 tables

People:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ben |
| 2 | John |
| 3 | Joey |

Pets:

| id | name | person_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doge | 1 |
| 2 | Catty | 2 |
| 3 | Reksi | 1 |

It's a 1 to many relationship, but I can't define foreign key because the order in which they may be inserted, so I define a default index for person_id

And I execute the following query:

```
select some_fields
from People
left outer join pets on person_id=id
where id=1
```

That I am trying to optimize.

Since the outer left join is being done on the provided id, can I execute this SQL asynchronously?

I am using JS and Sequelize (that generates this query), I can technically send 2 queries without joins and use promise.all() to send them both together, and then merge the results manually on JS.

But I was wondering if I can tell SQL to execute it like that so it will be more effective?

**Edit:**

The real query do 5 left outer joins from tables like pets, do it to get all info on one person for that example.
People is 180k table, and it do the left outer join  on 5 300~700k tables.

Indexing that person_id on all of these tables helped reduce the query from 5 to 2 seconds, but I still try to optimize it better, since 2 seconds is still a lot.

**Edit 2:**

By async I mean, and join on where clause I meant that since I am performing the join on the ID that I have when I fire the query, I can replace the above query with 2 queries:

```
select some_fields from People where id=1
```

And:

```
select some_fields from Pets where person_id=1
```

And execute them both in the same time with promise.all()

Comment: `I can't define foreign key because the order in which they may be inserted` - that doesn't seem right. As for offloading join from db to server - that's not a really good idea in general, and the fact your server is node.js-based doesn't help.

Comment: `outer left join` is not valid sql syntax on any platform I've used. Anyway do not entertain the thought that this will run quicker if you pull the records locally and join locally. Databases have been optimising this process for decades and you aren't going to trump that with some special client side code

Comment: If you have a performance issue, first step is to ensure there are indexes on join columns

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid my mistake, it's left outer join, and the person_id in the pets column is indexed. That helped reduce the query time from 5 seconds to 2, but 2 is still a lot.

Comment: I suggest you also index `People.id` Especially since you are also filtering on it (I think - you have no table aliases)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid People.id is primary key of the table, so it's indexed by default.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is there any "combined" index where I can pair the values from both tables?

Comment: You could try changing `pets.person_id` to be a clustered instead of non clustered index BTW my expertise is SQL Server no Postgres

Comment: You could also try a materialized view, but I think they are more trouble than they are worth https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html. Does your query take 2 seconds to run or 2 seconds to appear in your web page?

Comment: How many rows is the query returning? If it's returning 1 million rows it's bound to be slow.

Comment: Please include the exact query and its execution plan.

Comment: @TheImpaler Returning about 120~ rows

Comment: @eliezra236 If there's no aggregation (`GROUP BY`) or subqueries a query that returns 120 rows should be blazing fast -- with a response time in the order of milliseconds. There's probably a missing index. Please include the exact query and the execution plan.